# How do I return an unspecified Measurement<T> from a function?

Tags: swift, generics, opaque-types

UPDATE: Okay, I'm confused. My original code did not compile. At some point in cutting it down to a minimal example, it apparently started working. I have rewritten the original version enough now that I've lost track of why it didn't work in the first place. Going to just mark this question resolved.

---

I am trying to figure out how to write a function that returns an arbitrary Measurement, without having to specify in advance what UnitType the Measurement has. The following is more or less what I want to do, but it does not compile. (The arguments to the function don't matter.)

```
   func getValue(for x:Int) -> Measurement<Unit>? {
        if x==1 {
            return Measurement(value:5, unit:UnitSpeed.metersPerSecond)
        } else {
            return Measurement(value:2, unit:UnitLength.meters)
        }
    }
```

I don't want to have to care what the Unit is! Measurements encapsulate their unit, and all I want to do is plug it into something like: `Text(reading?.unit.symbol ?? "")` at the other end.

`func getValue(for measure:TrackedMeasure) -> some Measurement? {}` complains "Reference to generic type 'Measurement' requires arguments in <…>"

The suggested fix is `func getValue(for measure:TrackedMeasure) -> some Measurement<Unit>? { }`, which then complains "An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class"

There does not seem to *be* a protocol for Measurement, and I can't figure out how to define one.

Do I have to, like, reimplement Measurement to make this work?

Comment: Generics are a static-type thing. They don't erase types the way protocol do. Talking about a measurement without a unit is just a `Double. What's the root problem you're trying to solve with this code?

Comment: What is `TrackedMeasure`?  Can't really understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Do you have an example of what you want to pass in and get in return?

Comment: TrackedMeasure is just an enum. I want to pass in a value, select a measurement and return it. But the measurements aren't all the same type: I have a speed, and a distance, and an elapsed time.

Comment: Consider an example with specialized types. In your example, you want to a function to return either a `Measurement<UnitLength>` type or a `Measurement<UnitSpeed>` type. These are completely different types without a shared common base. You can return `Any`, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: It's still ambiguous what you're trying to accomplish.  More context would certainly help as it seems as though it could be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @clawesome please explain to me what is ambiguous about my question. I really don't see what is unclear or ambiguous or downvotable about: "How do you return a Measurement from a function without having to specify in advance what UnitType the Measurement has?"

Comment: Though it appears the answer may be "Swift actually makes it impossible to do this very reasonable-sounding thing."

Comment: @NewDev are they really completely different types? They have so much in common in the parts that I care about: specifically a \.value property that returns a Double and a \.unit property that returns a Unit. It seems like it ought to be possible to define a protocol implemented by both of them that I can use as a return type, but Swift has thwarted my every attempt.

Comment: @croald - for all intents and purposes, they are. When a compiler specializes a generic, it creates a new type. They are as different as `Foo` and `Bar` that happen to have the same properties.

Comment: @croald I can't tell what your intended use is as I don't know the context in how you're using the values.  When you say 'plug it in', the example you're giving looks to be a SwiftUI label.  Since you don't specify what `currentSpeed` and `currentDistance` are, I have to make assumptions what they are which I would assume them to be Measurements based on the return type but that seems to contradict the assumed intended use of displaying it in a label.  Then also, your example code looks like it already does what you're asking so it's ambiguous, in my opinion, to what the true issue is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Measurement<UnitType>` is a generic type and it does not extend a common base class or conform to a common protocol, so a concrete type `Measurement<UnitLength>` is a different type than `Measurement<UnitSpeed>`.

The only way around it is to do something like a type erasure, and have them both conform to a common protocol `AnyMeasurement`:

```
protocol AnyMeasurement {
  var baseUnit: Unit { get }
  var value: Double { get }
}
```

Then you can conform `Measurement` to `AnyMeasurement`:

```
extension Measurement: AnyMeasurement {
  // just need to return a base Unit, instead of a concrete UnitType
  // value: Double { get } is already implemented by Measurement
  var baseUnit: { self.unit }
}
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
func randomMeasurement() -> AnyMeasurement {
   let speed  = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitSpeed.metersPerSecond)
   let length = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.meters)

   return Bool.random() ? speed : length
}

print(randomMeasurement().baseUnit.symbol)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. So the common protocol has \.value and \.baseUnit, instead of Measurement's \.value and \.unit. It feels more like a wrapper than a common base class, but if that's the best we can do it will serve.

Comment: Well, it's an extension, not so much a wrapper. It makes all concrete types of `Measurement<T>` conform to a new protocol. For example, \.value is still literally the Measurement's own property

Answer (score 0):

```
enum TrackMeasure {
    case speed
    case distance
    case time
}

func getValue(for measure: TrackMeasure) -> Measurement<Unit> {

    switch measure {
        case .speed:
            return Measurement(value: 60, unit: UnitSpeed.milesPerHour)
        case .distance:
            return Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.miles)
        case .time:
            return Measurement(value: 6, unit: UnitDuration.minutes)
    }
}

let speed = getValue(for: .speed)
let distance = getValue(for: .distance)
let time = getValue(for: .time)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't want to *take* a generic measurement; I want to *return* a generic measurement.